# signtool fails to find certificate on Windows 10, due to private key filter

Tags: windows, driver-signing

I am the developer of UniversalADBDriver, a tool that creates a self signed Android USB driver on the user's computer.

Source code of installer and setup package:
https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver

The tool generates a keypair and adds a certificate to the user's key store, then signs the driver files. This worked fine until Windows 10, where it inexplicably stopped working. I ran the command line manually:

```
The following certificates were considered:
    Issued to: UniversalADB
    Issued by: UniversalADB
    Expires:   Fri Aug 25 17:00:00 2017
    SHA1 hash: C8701DF4CDC7DD75813400AD2B3B4C2EFDA4E662

After EKU filter, 1 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 1 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left.
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

On Windows 10, the certificate is being filtered out by the "Private Key filter". No idea what that is, no documentation anywhere on it.

UPDATE

I've discovered that neither makecert.exe or X509Store.add can write certificates/keys to the Current User store when invoked through the installer on Windows 10. However, the certificates in the Local Machine store are placed correctly. I'm not sure why that is. So basically, the private key is not being placed in the store properly so the signature fails. Running the same steps manually on the command line works. I still need to figure out why the private key is not being persisted in the store however.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_hardware_certification/archive/2015/04/01/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10.aspx

Comment: @Richard, Yes the test signing process is exactly what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: Have you looked at the /debug output to see if it gives anything useful?

Comment: @JaredPar that is the useful /debug output :)

Comment: @koush, what do mean under 'invoking through installer'? Do you do this in custom action?

Comment: @StenaviN makecert is called via the installer MSI during the install process. The install process does the following: generates a self signed cert, adds it to the cert store (or at least tries to), and signs the driver.

https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver

Comment: @StenavIN Correct, it is a custom action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using BouncyCastle to generate a certificate programatically. For some reason, this certificate does not seem to work anymore on Windows 10. I switched to packaging makecert.exe for the certificate generation, and that seemed to fix it.